# Troubles with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf

Good day!, I hope someone has the answer to this question. I'm having troubles when trying to "convert" an html to pdf from a rails application, I've followed these steps: http://www.snikt.net/blog/2012/04/26/wicked-pdf/ with no luck, when I click the link it only changes the url from "http://localhost:3000/users/3" to "http://localhost:3000/users.3" with a blank page.

Then I read that you must configure a few things first, so I follow these steps: http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/compilation, everything looks good until I reach the part with the "make && make install", here are the results:

cd src/lib/ && make -f Makefile 
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/username/wkhtmltopdf/src/lib'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for`first'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/username/wkhtmltopdf/src/lib'
cd src/pdf/ && make -f Makefile 
make[1]: Entering directory`/home/username/wkhtmltopdf/src/pdf'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `first'.
make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/username/wkhtmltopdf/src/pdf'
cd src/image/ && make -f Makefile 
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/username/wkhtmltopdf/src/image'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for`first'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/username/wkhtmltopdf/src/image'
cd src/lib/ && make -f Makefile install
make[1]: Entering directory`/home/username/wkhtmltopdf/src/lib'
mkdir: cannot create directory `/include': Permission denied
make[1]: *** [install_headers] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/username/wkhtmltopdf/src/lib'
make: *** [sub-src-lib-install_subtargets-ordered] Error 2

As a note the command "wkhtmltopdf some_url my_pdf.pdf" does work, the issue is when trying to "convert" an html, from a rails application, to pdf.

I appreciate every single tip you can give because I'm trully lost. I'm sorry if it's a dumb question and for all the troubles, and thank you for your time.

Comment: If wkhtmltopdf already works for URLs why would compiling/make install be required?  I may have misunderstood the question though as I don't use the rails wkhtmltopdf gem

Comment: Thanks for your time, I'm trying to install it because it's not working from my rails app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just go through all of that, following this tutorial: http://blog.tcs.de/install-wkhtmltopdf-on-ubuntu-server/
Thank you guys for your time.